# How to make my website not dangerous when doing a phishing awareness campaigns?

Tags: url, phishing, gophish

So I have a website that send phishing emails for employers and I get the results for this campaign (for example how many employees click on the link, etc)
While testing my website on my personal emails the website became dangerous.
What should I do ?

Comment: When you say "the website became dangerous", do you mean that google labeled your website as dangerous (even though it isn't)? EDIT: Also this question seems broad, could you narrow the scope down or give more information. Is this website using php etc.

Comment: Yeah google labeled my domain as phishing website. Edit: I’m using an open source phishing simulator called gophish (built with Golang and JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I run a phishing simulation service called [CanIPhish](https://caniphish.com/) and I came across this exact same issue when building my phishing websites.

What's happening here, is google is discovering and analysing your website through both it's normal indexing capability but also by scanning emails and detonating links.

When Google or it's threat intelligence partners discover your website it's analysing the content and accordingly flagging it as malicious.

To get around this issue, you need to hide the website behind a load-balancer or CDN which can perform conditional routing based on querystring parameters. Within the querystring you need to create a single-use GUID tied to the campaign and target. When the target detonates the link, they're forwarded to the phishing website and the GUID becomes inoperable. This way, when google or a threat intelligence partner index the site or detonate links in an email, they see something completely different to what your actual targets see.

I'm operating my myriad of phishing websites by hosting them on Amazon S3, I'm using Cloudfront as the CDN, Lambda@Edge on Cloudfront to inspect QueryString parameters and a mixture of DynamoDB with S3 for storing target user details and details on whether a GUID has already been detonated.

To see an example of this - try browsing [here](https://authwebmail.com/2/login.html) and all you'll see is a "Oops you clicked a phishing link" instead of the actual page which is a Google phishing site.